# How to pause during middle of animation/transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have an image that I want to stretch for 3 seconds, then pause for 2 seconds, then unstretch for 3 seconds. As it stands, I don't know how to pause it; animation-delay only works at the beginning of the animation, not the middle. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Page 2</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    /* Your styles go here */
    img {
        width:200px; 
        height:100px; 
        animation: widthChange 6s;
        -webkit-animation: widthChange 6s;
        -moz-animation: widthChange 6s;
        -0-animation: widthChange 6s;


    }

    p {text-align:center}
    button {margin:20px}
    .stylized {
        font-style: italic;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: yellow;
        border-style: outset;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}
    }
    @-o-keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}        }
    @-moz-keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}
    }
    @keyframes widthChange {
        0%, 100% {width: 200px;}
        50% {width: 400px;}

    }

    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       // jQuery methods go here...
       $(document).ready(function() {

        $('img').addClass("loaded");
        $('img').addClass("loaded2");
        $("#button1").click(function() {
            $("button").addClass("stylized");
            $("#button1").html("Fancy Button 1");
            $("#button2").html("Fancy Button 2");
            $("#button3").html("Fancy Button 3");
        });
       });

    });
    /* Your additional JavaScript goes here */
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img class = "image" src="elephant.jpg" alt="elephant"/>
    <p><button id="button1">Button 1</button><button id="button2">Button 2</button><button id="button3">Button 3</button></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this. If you add in the pause time to the total time (to get 8 seconds instead of 6), and then calculate the period of time that you want the element to be static (3/8 + 2/8, where 2/8 is the 2 second pause time), and then make the element return to the default width by the end (another 3/8ths of the total time), you should get a 2-second pause in between.

I used only the default `animation` and `@keyframes` here. You can copy this code into the other browser-specific versions for compatibility.

```
animation: widthChange 8s;

@keyframes widthChange {
    0% {width: 200px;}
    37.5% {width: 400px;}
    62.5% {width: 400px;}
    100% {width: 200px;}
}
```

Stripped-down example: http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/pjnk6z6f/

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding additional keyframes, like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/kh3qa3L6/

Eg:

```
@-webkit-keyframes widthChange {
    0%, 100% {
        width: 200px;
    }
    25% {
        width: 400px;
    }
    75% {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```